# embedded ruby code doesn't execute when I insert .txt file into div (Rails + jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, load

I am loading .txt files into a div in my file.html.erb. 
This works fine but when I embed ruby code like this <% Code %> in the .txt file that I am loading in it is just being displayed as text instead of executing it.

The other ruby code in the actual file.html.erb works normally so I figured I have to add something to my .txt file that I am loading in using JQuery .load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use something like

```
<% ERB.new('your file content here').result(binding) %>
```

If you need it rendered, you have to use `<%=` instead of `<%`

Comment: doesnt work for me. If I put this in the .txt file it still displays it as text when it is loading into the div.

Comment: @MarcThalen The answer's code is supposed to be used in the "file.html.erb" and the `your file content here` part has to be replaced with the txt file's contents.